# Get Table name from another query result

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have a table as like below:

```
Table AuditLog(
Reference varchar(10) [primary key],
TableName varchar(10),
ModifiedColumn varchar(10),
ChangeData varchar(max),
TableReference varchar(10)
)
```

I am trying to achieve following query:

```
select *,
    (select accountNumber from [AuditLog.TableName] where Reference = AuditLog.TableReference ) 
    from AuditLog
```

`AuditLog` table column '`TableName`' contain table name of that database. I need to load accountnumber from that table base on `TableReference`.

I need to create a view with query. What is the right way to have table name populated dynamically?

Comment: Construct the statement as text and use EXEC or sp_executesql(parameterized)

Comment: You will need dynamic sql for that.

Comment: I don't get the point why question mark as negative? lollzz

Comment: @Zohar: Can you not give us any example of your answer?

Comment: Can't really do that now since I'm using my phone and it's very hard to write code like this.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started:

```
DECLARE @SQL varchar(max)

SET @SQL = SELECT 'SELECT accountNumber 
                   FROM '+ TableName +' 
                   INNER JOIN AuditLog ON Reference = AuditLog.TableReference'
FROM AuditLog
WHERE <condition>

EXEC(@SQL)
```

**Note:** dynamic sql comes with a price, both as security hazards and as performance issues.
In this case, since there is no user input involved, the chances of being exposed to sql injection attacks are slimer (unless someone tampers with the `auditLog` table).

It might be a better choice to simply add to the `auditLog` table the value of the `accountNumber` with the other values it keeps, and then simply querying it directly.

Comment: I have like about 50 million row. Does this dynamic query create any loading time issue? Beside that I need to use this in a view. How it is possible?

Comment: I don't think it's possible using it in a view. you might want to add that column to the auditLog table.